# Maven command: mvn tomcat:run

Tags: tomcat6, maven-plugin

When using `mvn tomcat:run`, Maven downloads the Tomcat bundles into the target directory and the plugin starts this Tomcat instance with the web project. This Tomcat instance is not visible in Eclipse's server view.

But I have a local Tomcat 6 installed, can I configure the Tomcat Plugin in a way that it uses this local Tommcat instance (under CATALINA_HOME) instead of installing a new version into the target project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. The official doc for [tomcat:run](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/run-mojo-features.html) says:

*When developping a war project, you usually build your war and deploy it to an installed Tomcat instance. This is time and resources consuming and take time to install locally the instance.
The run mojo give you the opportunity to save that by simply running your war inside an embeded Tomcat instance in your Maven build.*

So I have to start the installed Tomcat instance in the server view and then the maven plugin is using this server instance for goals other then tomcat:run.

Answer (score 0):

1)upgrade your Tomcat to Tomcat 7,

2)Configure your Tomcat users.xml to include a set of credentials :

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>

<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user password="password" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-status, manager, admin-gui, admin-script, admin" username="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Your Maven .settings.xml:

```
<server>
        <id>local_tomcat</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
```

Create a new 'dev' profile with new Tomcat plugin:

```
<profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>tjb</finalName>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                            <server>local_tomcat</server>
                            <path>/</path>
                        </configuration>


                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: This explains how to install Tomcat, but doesn't explain my question.

Comment: @ChrLipp am confused then as you explicitly stated you want to know about 'configuration' and I don't see any instructions in my answer about installing Tomcat

Comment: Sorry, you are right. You are explaining how to config Tomcat. What I wanted to know is how to avoid that the maven tomcat:run starts an embedded Tomcat.

Comment: @ChrLippIn that case, look at my pom.xml snippet. Look at what it's doing. Provided that your local Tomcat is running, it deploys to the server through the manager application which runs by default if you haven't tinkered with the default Tomcat layout and files (other than the tomcat-users.xml).

Comment: When Tomcat is running, everything is fine. The issue is starting Tomcat by tomcat:run. In that case maven downloads and starts a tomcat instance in the target directory. I would have liked that maven starts the tomcat instance located under catalina_home, but it seams that this is not possible.

Comment: @ChrLipp are you sure you aren't still using the codehaus plugin? Use the apache tomcat plugin I posted above. They have taken over the plugin but the 'goals' have changed. You can now use: tomcat7:run-war